# I have never heard him to say it

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

> I have never heard him to say it

Now, I realize that the "to" is not supposed to be there. But why? Grammatically "say" in this sentence is an infinitive.  Or it is pretending to be one. I am using other languages to get to the bottom of this and "say" ends up being an infinitive in each of them.

Comment: Since when does a plain form have to be preceded by the infinitive marker, *to*? *Hear* takes a bare infinitival in your example (though it may take a *to*-infinitival in the passive: *He has never been heard to say it (by me)*). That's just how it is in English – different verbs behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

### It's a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)

Bare infinitives are commonly used for/with "perception" verbs (like hear, feel, feel) and auxiliary verbs (may, must, should).